Select all checkboxes in React Hook Form not working
I am trying to created a checkbox, on clicking which select all other checkboxes in react hook form, and on unchecking it will deselect all checkboxes. I also want to add selecting single checkbox feature also.
But I am confused how to do that.
I am trying using UseFieldArray and based on if value of selectAll checkbox is true, I am adding all other checkboxes. But it's not working. Could you please help with this If I am doing correct or I need go some other way like using onchange method, or append and remove methods to update checked value of checkbox. So
  const {
    fields: agreementfields,
    append: agreementappend,
    remove: agreementremove,
  } = useFieldArray({ control, name: "agreementitem" });


 <input         
          type="checkbox"
          value="true"
          {...register("agreementall", {
                    required: "Agreement is required",
                    validate: {
                      isall: (cvalue) => {
                        if (cvalue) {
                          setValue("agreementfields", ["checkbox1value", "checkbox2value"]);
                        } else {
                          setValue("agreementfields", [""]);
                        }
                      },
                    },
                  })}
                />


  <input     
           type="checkbox"
           value="checkbox1value"
           checked={agreementfields.includes("checkbox1value")}
           {...register("agreement2", {
                    required: "Agreement2 is required",
                  })}
                />
  <input         
              type="checkbox"
              value="checkbox2value"
              checked={agreementfields.includes("checkbox2value")}
              {...register("agreement3", {
                    required: "Agreement3 is required",
                  })}
                />

I am trying to created a checkbox, on clicking which select all other checkboxes in react hook form, and on unchecking it will deselect all checkboxes. I also want to add selecting single checkbox feature also.
